# i type this and i am getting error what i should do

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy
x=numpy.arange(-10,10,1)
print(len(x))
```

and i am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/WIZ/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/numpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:/Users/WIZ/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32\numpy.py", line 2, in <module>
    x=numpy.arange(-10,10,1)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arange' (most likely due to a circular import)
>>>
```

Comment: Try: `import numpy as np x=np.arange(-10,10,1) print(len(x))`

Comment: i tried but nothing happen

Comment: Please read (again) the [how-to ask help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: This works fine for me. Is your file named `numpy.py` ?

Comment: Kindly tick-mark the correct answer, if it helped...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a file name `numpy.py` in the same folder as this file. Please rename or remove it.